# Jackson. Сериализация объектов

Tags: java, json, jackson

Я хочу сериализовать объект в json строку

```
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(myObject);
```

но предварительно мне нужно добавить дополнительные поля, которых нет в определении класса объекта. Можно ли это сделать средствами Jackson?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jn = mapper.valueToTree(new MyClass(1, "aaa"));
ObjectNode on = (ObjectNode)jn;
on.put("zxc", "zzzz");
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(on);
```

Если класс будет такой:

```
public class MyClass {
    int qwe;
    String asd;

    public MyClass(int qwe, String asd) {
       this.qwe = qwe;
      this.asd = asd;
    }
   //...
}
```

то получим json {"qwe":1,"asd":"aaa","zxc":"zzzz"}